# Execute sql delete query foreach user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible execute sql delete query foreach user_id in table?
I can get all user_id with `SELECT user_id FROM`users
Then I can delete all raws except last with

```
DELETE FROM accounts
WHERE id IN (select * from (SELECT id 
FROM   accounts 
WHERE  user_id = 150192618395339835 
       AND site = 'https://www.paypal.com' 
       AND time_added < (SELECT Max(time_added) 
                         FROM   accounts 
                         WHERE  user_id = 150192618395339835 
                                AND site = 'https://www.paypal.com') 
ORDER  BY time_added ASC) as t)
```

How can I pass all user_id to delete query?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
WHERE user_id in (SELECT u.user_id FROM users u)
```

And all query:

```
DELETE FROM accounts
WHERE id IN (select * from (SELECT id 
FROM   accounts 
WHERE  user_id in (SELECT u.user_id FROM users u) 
       AND site = 'https://www.paypal.com' 
       AND time_added < (SELECT Max(time_added) 
                         FROM   accounts 
                         WHERE  user_id = 150192618395339835 
                                AND site = 'https://www.paypal.com') 
ORDER  BY time_added ASC) as t)
```

Comment: what about second where?